# Windows Media Player says "improperly installed" and won't start

Tags: windows-media-player, windows-10-v1803

Seems like after installing Windows 10 1803, Windows Media Player won't start for me.  It always says

> Windows Media Player is not installed properly and must be
>   reinstalled.Do you want to install the Player from the Microsoft Web
>   site?

I've tried removing and re-adding through Optional Features but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the "Windows Media Player Plus!" add-on I had installed was the issue. There's a newer version out (2.10) that resolved the compatibility issue with the Spring update.